# Trying to make a single page application using window.onpopstate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, single-page-application, popstate

I have something like a single page web application. To handle a back button click from the user I use the 'popstate' event

Here it is:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () { 
      
   backOneStep(0); // do my own job (get user to previous application screen)
   history.pushState(null, null, '');

});
```

In Firefox and Safari, the event works fine. When the user presses the "back" button - `backOneStep` is executed

For a long time everything was fine, but! But in Chrome, after the latest updates, the `popstate` event **is not firing if the previous `history.pushState` call was initiated from code**

So:
If you press the back button once, you will find yourself one screen of the application back.

If you press the button a second time, you will be kicked out of my application :(

What confusing me - if you click anywhere on the page **before the second click**, the event will fire a second time too

I made simple example - https://w.ip.cv.ua/popstate.html